# Installing Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

Docker promises to make sharing applications easier, fixing the problem of complaints like "It works on my machine but not on another machine"

I have not used docker for long enough to know if the promise if fulfilled.  It is clear that it will only be true if everyone has docker installed on every machine.  Most of my clients run on Windows and do not have docker installed.

Installing docker on Windows is a hassle.  Documentation of the process that I found is wrong or outdated, confusing and written by authors who are far more familiar with Linux than Windows.

What is a simple bare bones installation process that can be followed to just get it done?

Answer (score -1):

After struggling with this for several days, I have come up with this process which seems to work:

1. Open powershell as administrator
2. In powershell, type: dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
3. In powershell, type: dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
4. In browser, go to the website https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/  and download the installer for docker dektop for windows.
5. Run the installer "Docker Desktop Installer.exe"
6. Download the Linux kernel update package from https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi
7. Run the installer "wsl_update_x64.msi"
8. In powershell, type: wsl --set-default-version 2
9. Restart windows.

---

A quick check that the installation was succesful:

1. In a command prompt type: docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
2. Open browser to http://localhost

You should see a page with lots of information about docker.  Warning: some of this information is either outdated or does not apply to windows.

Comment: It might be easier if you just run `wsl --install`.  Additionally `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` and `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VirtualMachinePlatform` are actually PowerShell commands.  The DISM commands can be run within Command Prompt.

Comment: "It might be easier if you just run wsl --install"  When ( at what step )?  In a command prompt?

Comment: The first and only step other than rebooting your system and installing Docker

Comment: @Ramhound  You seem to have a much simpler process to offer.  Please post your complete process as an answer so I can check it out.  ( I have followed many recommended procedures that claimed to be simple and complete - they all left out steps that result in docker refusing to run.  )

Comment: I am making a suggestion to your answer.  I have already provided all the steps.

Comment: You have?  Where is your list of steps?

Comment: @Ramhound  You keep hinting that you know the answer to my question.  Could you please post your answer.  The poor documentation and lack of help indicates that Docker is not really intended to be used on Windows.